# Incompatible Shape between input image and expected model input image

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train a FCN model for segmentation. I have an array of train images of size (256,256,3) and another array of ground truth(masks) of size (256,256,3). My model summary is as below :
[Model Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5IwQ.png)

I am not sure how to train the model so i am using model.fit() to train it.

[Model Compile and fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZNyw.png)

But i am getting incompatible input image size error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJZs7.png)

Can anyone, please help me to rectify the code and train the model. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your output's shape 256 256 3? Check it in summary

Comment: And what shape of your input data arrays please

Comment: The shape of input array (tr_im) is (436, 256, 256, 3) [436 samples in total with shape 256,256,3]  and the same is for ground truth (tr_grd). I have changed the inputs to model.fit by converting tr_img and tr_grd to arrays but now the problem is with the output at last layer of model of shape (None, 8, 8, 5) and shape of ground truth ((None, 256, 256, 3) . Is there any way i can train the model . I even tried using padding='same' , but it didnt work.

Comment: For semantic segmentation you need decoder, not simple fullyconnected layers -> need other arch. Take a look at https://github.com/giovanniguidi/FCN-keras